# ScrollViewer That Contains a Grid Snaps Back to the Top When Let Go

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm using a ScrollViewer to enable the Grid that it contains to be scrollable. However, when I let go after scrolling down, it will automatically scroll back to the top of the Grid.

```
<ScrollViewer>

    <Grid ShowGridLines="false" MinHeight="700">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1" /> 
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Pivot1Rows[0].RowHeight}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Pivot1Rows[1].RowHeight}" /> 
            <RowDefinition Height="1" />
            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Pivot1Rows[2].RowHeight}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Stackpanels for each row/column combo here -->
     </Grid>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Any idea what I need to add/change to ensure the position within the Grid scrolled down to is maintained even after I let go?

Comment: Silly me ... Was about to say: it works ... But then saw the phone 8 :) if it's any comfort, it works on WPF & Windows :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the height of the ScrollViewer to be less than that of the Grid. If the ScrollViewer is larger than it's child, the child will always bounce back to it's original position.

Comment: That has helped but not completely fixed the issue. I've set the height of the ScrollViewer to 700 and the Grid to 800. I can scroll down a little bit and the scrollbar's position will be maintained. However, if I try to scroll down to the very bottom of the Grid, it will still snap back slightly. That is, it won't snap back to the top of the Grid but will jump slightly resulting in the content at the bottom of the Grid to not be visible. Any ideas?

Comment: Try toying around with the heights until you get it how you would like. I think making the grid bigger should be the way to go.